# Writing WebTests using Visual Studio 2013 for a website written in C# and Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, webtest

I am writing a WebTest using Visual Studio 2013 for a website implemented in C# and JavaScript. Here are the steps that I am following, and the issue I am running into.
**Note**: I do not have access to the source code for the website

**Steps**:

1. Record the WebTest, which requires uploading a PDF file.
2. When the file to upload is selected, JavaScript executes and generates a unique, dynamic, GUID to identify the file to upload. Uploading the same file again, generates a new GUID.
3. The unique GUID is used as part of the HTTP request to send to the server.
4. When replaying the WebTest, the same (recorded) GUID is used, which makes the

   test fail.

My question is:
Since JavaScript does not execute when replaying the WebTest, is there a way to generate the GUID when replaying the WebTest? If not, is there a work-around?
I appreciate any hints to solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you the suggestion. That  would have worked, but I have just learned that the recorded value is also used within the application to link the uploaded file to the user's profile. It sounds like the application would need to change to capture that value, as a hidden field, for example, or some other means.  So, by creating a new GUID, the test would still fail because the GUID that I would create through the Plugin and the application's GUID would be different. Thoughts?

Comment: If you are responding to my answer then it would have been best to add a comment on my answer. Please [edit] your question to explain the problem in more detail. Does item (2) in the question still apply? Does the Javascript code generate the GUID? I answered the original question but your comment only hints at the more complex issue.

Comment: It is over two weeks since your last activity on this question. Has the problem been resolved? If yes then please write an answer. If no then please [edit] the question to add more details so that someone else may be able to give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `WebTestRequest` [plugin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514192(v=vs.120).aspx). In its `PreRequestDataBinding` method create a GUID and save it to a context parameter. Add the plugin to the recorded request and modify that request to use the GUID value in the context parameter.

Something based upon the following (untested) code should work:

```
public class CreateGuid : WebTestRequestPlugin
{
    public string GuidCp { get; set; }

    public override void PreRequestDataBinding(object sender, PreRequestDataBindingEventArgs e)
    {
        Guid newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        e.WebTest.Context[GuidCp] = newGuid.ToString();
    }
}
```

You may need to set a particular Guid format via [a parameter to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx) `ToString`.